# I want to know where are the timer jobs, webparts and user controls saved?

Tags: web-part, timer-jobs, content-database, user-controls

Are they saved in the content db or Layouts folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webparts are stored in content database, User Controls are stored in Layouts. Timer jobs configuration is stored in farm configuration database but run under SharePoint timer service account. I believe custom timer jobs dll are stored in Gac.

Comment: Timer jobs configuration are stored in the Farm Configuration database.

Comment: @Naim, Ta, It was a typo.